# java search for `closable` objects, where close was not called

Tags: java, resources, lint, resource-leak, memory-leak-detector

Look like I have memory leak in project, and I was able to find 2 methods, where `closable` resources were created, but `close` method was never called.

Is it possible to scan project, to find resources without `close` method call?

Anybody use lints for such purposes? Any suggestions may help. Thx.

Comment: "where closable resources were created" Nit: that's a *resource* leak, not a memory leak necessarily.

Answer (score 0):

For identifying a memory leak you can enable verbose garbage collection in your JVM configuration(-verbose:gc). Which is showing detailed information about your GC. Summary reports are shown in the default error file, it will help you to understand how your memory is used. And from that reports you might guess such issues.